# Why isn't jcarousel.on() executed?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JavaScript code.

```js
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.gsdOmega4ExampleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var jcarousel = $('.home-jcarousel');
      console.log('executed');
      jcarousel.on('jcarousel:create jcarousel:reload', function() {
        console.log('never executed');
      })
      console.log('executed');
  };
})(jQuery);
```

`jcarousel` is correctly referenced. I don't understand why `jcarousel.on()` is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because `on()` didn't exist before jQuery 1.7, and Drupal ships with...well, not 1.7.

The standard solution is to install [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) and select 1.7 as the version for the site.

For future reference, check for JS errors in the browser console - there will be something very similar to this in there:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: That error was throw in the console yesterday before I changed the version to 1.7 with jQuery Update. Today, no error is thrown but the code still doesn't get executed.

Comment: If you've confirmed the correct element is being selected, and you have no errors, you'll need to take this over to jCarousel's support forum to ask why those events aren't responding. I'm afraid we can't help to support third party JS libraries here for obvious reasons. Not to be picky, but the code _is_ being executed if you have no errors - it's just not doing what the jCarousel docs have presumably told you it will (which is why you need to go to them for support)